# Facebook Page Tab tabs_added/signed request with PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am revamping the attachment of our Page Tab app using the "Add Page Tab", and am a little unsure about the flow. This is what I'm trying to do:

1) direct our users to the Add Page Tab dialog with our appId (works)
2) our redirect URL is hit with a post that has the "tabs_added" parameter
3) I use this code to try and get information about the FB account that is getting to my app:

```
$this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                                    'app_id' => <app_id>,
                                    'app_secret' <app secret>,
                                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9'
                                  ]);
$tabs_added = PARAM('tabs_added');
```

If I get a 'tabs_added' parameter, I'm assuming that means someone is "attaching" my app to their page, and I want to get information (specifically UID) for their account:

```
$helper = $this->fb->getPageTabHelper();
$signedRequest = $helper->getSignedRequest();
```

This call returns nothing

```
$parsed_signed_request = FacebookSignedRequest::parse_signed_request( $signedRequest, <app secret> );
```

This call fails because there is no signed request.

What am I missing? I am using v5 of the Facebook PHP API.

thanks

Comment: There will never be a signed request, because the user is just redirected to your URL in their browser. You can not get the ID of the user that added your app to their page.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.